# Multiplication and division on integers split into parts

Tags: c++, math, operator-overloading, uint

Does anyone know where I might get instructions on how to do multiplication and division (and maybe even modulus) on integers that are stored in parts? im making a library that stores a `uint128_t` as `uint64_t UPPER, LOWER`.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269268/) contains several useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with `GMP` library? Why don't you use it instead of implementing your own?

- [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/)

From the above link, you can download `tar.bz` file for Unix-based OS.

For Windows, see this link:

- [GMP Install Instruction for Windows Platform](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/)

It has lots of information and installation file for MinGW, MSVC++, and CgyWin. Download that suits your need. You can also see these link:

- [How to Install and Run GMP on Windows Using MPIR](http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-to-install-and-run-gmp-on-windows-using-mpir/)
- [Building GMP library with Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017058/building-gmp-library-with-visual-studio) (Stackover topic)

---

After you're done with installation and configuration, you would like to know how to program using GMP, for that browse through these links:

- [GMP Basics](http://gmplib.org/manual/GMP-Basics.html#GMP-Basics)
- [GMP Manual](http://gmplib.org/manual/)

Comment: @calccrypto: Of course, you've to download and install it, before using it.

Comment: install??? i thought it was just decompress, copy into some folder, and link the compiler to it

Comment: @calccrypto: Yes. That whole process is installation, with configuration and all.

Comment: there is no "gmp.h" file in the tar.gz

Comment: @calccrypto: Most certainly, you've downloaded the wrong file, or maybe there is some problem with the download.

Comment: ive downloaded it multiple times, and it never had the .h file. i went out of my way to find it, and managed to fine it. unfortunately, i deleted the entire folder and tar.bz by accident. besides. i could never get mpz_t working

Comment: please tell me where in the folder after it is extracted, the gmp.h file is located

Comment: @calccrypto: Are you using Windows or Linux? or what?

Comment: @calccrypto: It requires proper installation without which you cannot have `gmp.h` which is created when you install it by running the given installation script. see this : http://gmplib.org/manual/Installing-GMP.html#Installing-GMP

Comment: @calccrypto: Before using it, must read the GMP Basics : http://gmplib.org/manual/GMP-Basics.html#GMP-Basics

Comment: @calccrypto: That is what I was suspecting. The `tar.bz` you've download is for unix only, not for windows. Anyway, see my answer. I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Having your numbers splitted that way is an ideal prerequisite for [Karatsuba multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm). Consider:

```
x = x1 * 2^k + x2
y = y1 * 2^k + y2
```

Using the school multiplication, you would need 4 multiplications:

```
x*y = (x1*y1) * 2^(2*k) + (x1*y2 + x2*y1) * 2^k + x2*y2
```

Karatsuba needs a few more additions, but only 3 multiplications:

```
p1 = x1 * y1
p2 = x2 * y2
x*y = p1 * 2^(2*k) + ((x1+x2)*(y1+y2) - p1 - p2) * 2^k + p2
```

Of course the problem is how to deal with overflows.

Comment: In my tests, Karatsuba multiplication was slower unless I had a lot more than two "digits".

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic might be a good start. There are plenty of open source libraries already

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the various Big Integer libraries.  Here's one that google found https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/