# How to define and use numbers smaller than 2e-308

Tags: c++

Smallest double is 2.22507e-308. Is there any way I can use smaller numbers? 
I found a library called gmp, but have no idea how to use it, documentation is not clear at all, and I'm not sure if it works on windows.

I don't expect to give me instructions, but maybe at least some piece of advice.

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: A 'double' is a type that the CPU handles perfectly, in the way that CPU 'float' (as opposed to integer) registers work normally with 8 bytes at once. Can you give a reason for your "smaller numbers" necessity?

Comment: I use Visual Studio and it's native compiler.

Comment: I need smaller numbers to calculate exact gamma function values of high frequency complex argument.

Comment: ***I'm not sure if it works on windows.*** It does. ***GMP's main target platforms are Unix-type systems, such as GNU/Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, Mac OS X/Darwin, BSD, AIX, etc. It also is known to work on Windows in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode.***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017058/building-gmp-library-with-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

If you need really big precision, then give `gmp` chance. I am sure it works on Windows too.

If you just need bigger precision than `double`, try `long double`. It may or may not give you more, depends on your compiler and target platform.

In my case it does give more (gcc 6, x86_64 linux):

Test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::cout << "float:"
        << " bytes=" << sizeof(float)
        << " min=" << std::numeric_limits<float>::min()
        << std::endl;

    std::cout << "double:"
        << " bytes=" << sizeof(double)
        << " min=" << std::numeric_limits<double>::min()
        << std::endl;

    std::cout << "long double:"
        << " bytes=" << sizeof(long double)
        << " min=" << std::numeric_limits<long double>::min()
        << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
float: bytes=4 min=1.17549e-38
double: bytes=8 min=2.22507e-308
long double: bytes=16 min=3.3621e-4932
```

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler/architecture allows it, you could use something like `long double`, which compiles to an 80-bit float (though I think it aligns to 128 bits, so there's a bit of wasted space) and has more range and precision than a typical `double` value. Not all compilers will do that though, and on many compilers, `long double` is equivalent to a `double`, at 64-bits.

"gmp" is one library you could use for extended precision floats. I generally recommend [boost.multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html), which includes gmp, though personally, I'd use `cpp_bin_float` or `cpp_dec_float` for my multiprecision needs (the former is IEEE756 compliant, the latter isn't)

As for how to use them: I haven't used gmp, so I can't comment on its syntax, but `cpp_bin_float` is pretty easy to use:

```
typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_quad quad;
quad a = 34;
quad b = 17.95467;
b += a;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    b *= b;
}
std::cout << "This might be rather big: " << b << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your compiler to `gcc` or `Intel` type `long double` will be supported with bigger precission (80-bit). With default visual studio compiler, I have no advice for you what to do.